# rewriting URL seem to be written wrong

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just realised that some of my rewritten urls stopped working. I am unaware of why.

Here is my rewrite file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/locate/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&tlocate=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^changelogs/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/$ /forums.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/action/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/section/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&sectionid=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^register/([^/]*)/$ /register.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^account/([^/]*)/$ /account-page.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^about-us/$ /about.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/topic/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&topic=$2 [L]

ErrorDocument 400   /error.php
ErrorDocument 401   /error.php
ErrorDocument 403   /error.php
ErrorDocument 404   /error.php
ErrorDocument 500   /error.php
```

If i went to [www.localhost/account/](http://localhost/account/)

It would just send me to [www.localhost/forums/](http://localhost/forums/)

So i downloaded mozilla to see if my htaccess stopped working. The css didnt work there. I then went to a website to check my code and it complained about the line

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/$ /about.php
```

On that line, i tried to rewrite [www.localhost/about.php](http://www.localhost/about.php)
 into [www.localhost/about-us/](http://www.localhost/about-us/)

without any success. What is it that i'm doing wrong that causes this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/locate/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&tlocate=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^changelogs/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/$ /forums.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/action/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/section/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&sectionid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^register/([^/]*)/$ /register.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/([^/]*)/$ /account-page.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/$ /about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/topic/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&topic=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 400   /error.php
ErrorDocument 401   /error.php
ErrorDocument 403   /error.php
ErrorDocument 404   /error.php
ErrorDocument 500   /error.php
```

And add this code in your `about.php` HTML code:

```
<base href="/">
```

Because you change the root (for css and others relatives) with your `about-us/` link.

Comment: You're a king my friend, tho i had a basetag already. But the rest worked